# What shloka in Bhagvatgita says that it is a sin to tolerate injustice?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I have seen many pages which attribute this quote to Geeta, but I could not find the shloka which says this.

Comment: may be [2.33](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=33&etadi=1)..but not exactly the same..